# Prometheus remote_write

Tags: linux, prometheus

I am not very familiar with these components but I am trying.
I have Grafana and Prometheus installed on an Ubuntu server on my local network.
Prometheus is collecting the own Linux metrics using Node Exporter and I can display the metrics on Grafana using the Prometheus data source. So, I assume that on this side, for local use, both Prometheus and Grafana, are correctly set.

I have installed Prometheus also on a Raspberry Pi which is also on my local network.
I did manage to remote write the metrics relevant the Raspberry Pi to Grafana Cloud.
Now I am attempting to remote write the same metrics to the Grafana on the Ubuntu server mentioned above but I am not succeeding.

In the prometheus.yml on the Raspberry Pi, I have replaced this (which is working):

```
#remote_write:
#- url: https://prometheus-blocks-prod-us-central1.grafana.net/api/prom/push
  #name: grafana_cloud_prometheus
  #basic_auth:
    #username: something
    #password: something
```

with this:

```
remote_write:
- targets: "http://10.0.0.164/prometheus/remote/write"
  name: Prometheus
  basic_auth:
    username: admin
    password: admin
```

username and password are those set in Grafana.

When I restart the Prometheus service on the Pi, it fails:

> Process: 8698 ExecStart=/home/pi/prometheus/prometheus
> --config.file=/home/pi/prometheus/prometheus.yml --storage.tsdb.path=/home/pi/prometheus/data --log.level=debug (code=e  Main PID: 8698 (code=exited, status=2)

I am not sure about what I am doing wrong or if I am missing something somewhere here.
I did try to manipulate the target using only the server IP, IP and port, but I am not succeeding.
I would appreciate some help to get this right. Thanks

Comment: Check logs to learn for sure but I bet it's the unknown (`targets`) key in remote_write config. Try `url` instead.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to write data from Prometheus at Raspberry PI to Prometheus at Ubuntu server, then you need to enable remote_write capability at Prometheus server running on Ubuntu - see [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/feature_flags/#remote-write-receiver). Alternatively, you can write the collected metrics to other Prometheus-compatible system running on Ubuntu such as [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics). It [accepts data via Prometheus remote_write protocol out of the box](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#prometheus-setup).

I'd recommend also trying to run [Prometheus in Agent mode](https://prometheus.io/blog/2021/11/16/agent/) or to run [vmagent](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/vmagent.html) instead of Prometheus in default mode at Raspberry PI. These systems allow scraping Prometheus targets in the same way as Prometheus does, but they use lower amounts of compute resources (CPU, RAM, disk space, disk IO) compared to Prometheus.

Comment: Thank you for the directions. Concerning remote_write, I thought that should be enabled on the Pi which I did as per my .yml extract in my question above. I haven't found samples on how to enable remote_write on the server side. Could you please give an example? As I said I am not familiar with these components. Thank you

Comment: The built-in remote write receiver can be enabled by setting the --web.enable-remote-write-receiver command line flag. When enabled, the remote write receiver endpoint is /api/v1/write

https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/storage/#overview

Answer (score 3):

You can't remote write to Grafana (the visualization software), it accesses data by querying Prometheus itself. Remote write is meant to be used to write to other Prometheus instances, long term storage backends (like Thanos  and Cortex) or SaaS platforms (like Grafana Cloud).

What you probably want to do is add that Prometheus instance as a datasource in Grafana.

Comment: I already added the Prometheus datasource to Grafana on the server . I am battling to connect the Prometheus on the Pi to the Ubuntu server where a prometheus instance is running as well as Grafana and the Prometheus datasource for Grafana.

Comment: It is a bit confusing but, yes I would like to add the Prometheus instance on the Pi as datasource for Grafana on the server.

Answer (score 0):

your grafana already have prometheus like datasource so you can't use remote write in grafana, you can use remote write in a remote TSDB like victoriametrics or thanos to store metrics scraped by prometheus and then connect that TSDB with grafana